# Почему не приходит письмо?

Tags: php

HTML:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
                <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="uzinouzi.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="uzi.no.uzi.web@gmail.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заказ">
                <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="mail" required>
                <textarea name="message" id="textarea" placeholder="Сообщение" required></textarea>
                <button id='sendApp'>Отправить</button>
            </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
?>
```

Поставил все на локальный хост, через Open Server.

```
alert("Thank you!");
```

После нажатия на кнопку, т.е. все успешно прошло, но ничего на почте нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Думаю у вас почта не настроена на локалхосте, по моему в Open Server можно посмотреть почту которая якобы должна была отправиться.

Comment: [Fri Dec 29 12:06:47.013451 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9156:tid 200] AH01909: miki.loc:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Dec 29 12:06:47.014441 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9156:tid 200] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Dec 29 12:06:47.042532 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9156:tid 200] AH00354: Child: Starting 32 worker threads.

Apache отладка, miki.loc это домен который я сделал.

Comment: если не настроена почта, то надо смотреть в `OpenServer\userdata\temp\email\`

Comment: Настроил почту, но в логах мне пишет, что отправляется не на тот майл, который мне нужно(я случайно, когда первый раз отправлял не тот майл в инпут ввел, он сохранился похоже где-то), как поменять? В инпуте я сменил.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/htq3zw - Вот логи, я исправил проблему с неправильным email-om

http://prntscr.com/htq4e7 - Вот настройки почты.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi а где у вас вызов события сабмита формы?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin Я не разбираюсь в PHP, я взял готовы скрипт.